# meaning of "codnaturalistic dialogue"

Tags: meaning-in-context

1. What is a ***"codnaturalistic dialogue"***?
2. What or who does ***"its"*** refer to? Does it refer to EastEnders?

Context:

> When asked to enact scenes in their drama classes, children of primary
>   school age were more than likely to provide the latest storyline from
>   Grange Hill or EastEnders, with **its codnaturalistic** dialogue, and
>   to ‘compose’ music in the manner of the band of their choice. What
>   else did they know?
>
> [Sian Ede](https://books.google.com/books?id=iiE3RsvK248C&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22When%20asked%20to%20enact%20scenes%20in%20their%20drama%20classes%22&source=bl&ots=Cu21reCnxb&sig=YwmZAyy96Zk5kukQkMpVlnLNY3I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI4L2mr-7hyAIVQQoaCh1zGgNq#v=onepage&q=%22When%20asked%20to%20enact%20scenes%20in%20their%20drama%20classes%22&f=false)

Comment: I'd take it to mean carrying on a conversation with a fish.

Answer (score 1):

The text has the hyphenated "cod-naturalistic."  Likely this means faux- or sham-naturalistic, from the sense of *cod* as a mock, sham or hoax.  So Ede claims that the dialogue on the named shows attempts to be true to the dialect of the folks the characters represent, but it's really not authentic.

*Its* refers to *EastEnders*, although from what little I know about both shows, I'm not sure why the dialogue comment wouldn't also apply to *Grange Hill*

Comment: But feel free to interpret *cod-* as the fish.  This is Sian Ede, so that will make just as much sense in the end as anything else.